# what is the affect on real GDP and price level because of a new information in the stock market?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

There is one company in an economy which has a fixed supply of shares in the
short run. Suppose there is new information that causes expectations of lower profits.
How does this new stock market equilibrium affect final output and the final price level of the economy if you assume that autonomous consumption spending and household
wealth are positively related?

**My Understanding**

I have never read or tried to connect stock market to national income accounting even through Monetary Policy effects. But i have read a little about the effects of new information in the market.

I think because the new information is showing less confidence in the company so, through stock market, investment in the company will fall and hence the inventory of the company will fall. This fall in inventory will lead to fall in GDP, as it is given that autonomous consumption spending and household wealth are positively related this means that due to negative change in the inventory, consumption and household income will be negatively affected. Because we are talking about short run, that fall in the demand for the company's product will be accompanied by some layoffs and/or wage reduction. Hence the result should be *Fall in Real GDP and price level*.
please tell me if I'm wrong, thank you.